# Why does PCIe still hold on to 'transfers/second' instead of bits/second or symbols/second?

Tags: pcie, data-rate

I think it is kinda all covered in the title. To my (incomplete) knowledge, PCIe is the only modern bus that still expresses its rate in transfers per second. Is there, apart from 'tradition' any reason for this?

I understand that you might not want to use bit/second, but everyone else uses symbols/second in those cases - why is PCIe special?

Comment: DDR DRAM is also measured in transfers per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCI (without the "e") is a parallel bus and, quite sensibly it is rated in transfers (of a parallel quantity) per second and, I suspect that to keep things compatible for the guys who read specifications from the top-down, it was easier to talk about the same quantity. Hidden beneath that quantity is the bit rate but, this is hardware specific and potentially not useful to many people.

Comment: I was about to write something very similar, then realized that of course you find things like "PCIe3 with x16 lanes allows for so-and-so-many GT/s", where "so-and-so-many" is 16 times the rate of a single lane… that's also very confusing (because, low-level-*technologically*, these 16 lanes are independent serial links, but not-quite-as-low-level, they are one 16-lane parallel bus… uff)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Andy. It might be that, because I'm on the 'designing the actual silicon' side, I got more confused by the higher-level 'total transfer rates'. I'm just used to SERDES being a single 'this is the symbolrate'.

Comment: @JorenVaes But that leads to a question; what do you consider as the symbol rate on PCIe then? That's easy when you have a fixed clock and simple 8b10b coding of bytes to symbols, but what about when you are using 128b130b coding? There is a Wikipedia article on "Transfers_per_second" for further info.

Comment: @Justme, I don't see how this has any impact on symbolrate. Symbol rate is just the amount of symbols you send on a low level. The fact that you don't encode 1 bit (or 2 bits for PAM4, etc) in this on a higher level doesn't care. 
I think my confusion comes from ethernet trancievers, where people will say the bitrate of 50 gbit ethernet is 56 gbit/s. The fact that on a protocol level you have all this overhead is 'irrelevant' when you are designing the final SERDES. You are still transmittign 56 gbit/second at a symbolrate of 28 Gbaud.